# Justification for: "$f(1/x)$ has the same roots as $g(x)$, if it is multiplied by some monomial s.t. the leading term is $x^3$ they will be equal"

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Problem statement:**
A solution:L
Let $g(x)$ be a polynomial with leading coefficient $1,$ whose three roots are the reciprocals of the three roots of $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c,$ where $1<a<b<c.$ What is $g(1)$ in terms of $a,b,$ and $c?$

**A solution:**
Note that $f(1/x)$ has the same roots as $g(x)$, if it is multiplied by some monomial so that the leading term is $x^3$ they will be equal. We have$f(1/x) = \frac{1}{x^3} + \frac{a}{x^2}+\frac{b}{x} + c$ so we can see that $g(x) = \frac{x^3}{c}f(1/x)$ Therefore $g(1) = \frac{1}{c}f(1) =\frac{1+a+b+c}c$

**My question:**

I was able to solve this problem using Vieta's theorem. I am not, however, able to see how this solution works. How can this be justified: "Note that $f(1/x)$ has the same roots as $g(x)$, if it is multiplied by some monomial so that the leading term is $x^3$ they will be equal?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $p,q,r$ be roots of $g(x)$ $$g(x)=(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)$$ then $f(x)=(x-1/p)(x-1/q)(x-1/r)\to f(1/x)=(1/x-1/p)(1/x-1/q)(1/x-1/r)$

$$\implies \underbrace {{-pqrx^3}}_{\text {monomial}}f(1/x)=g(x)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea why the assumption $1<a<b<c$ is needed?

Comment: @gewbDog5 I dont see why that info was given